# Adding a value calories together with price of product

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, simple-product

I am making a website for food products. I wish to add a value calorie count with every product that would add up like price of product when choosing many products in the cart. How can I do this in Magento 2? I wish to do this for simple as well as bundled products.